# Do I have to reset all camera paramters if I change one [Android Camera Parameters]?

Tags: android, parameters, camera, android-camera

I couldn't find any information about that in the android docs. 
So here is my question:

When I change one parameter of my camera, do I then have to reset all parameters I have set before or can I be sure that they will not be affected by another call to `mCamera.setParameters(params)`?

For instance, when I update the zoom value by calling

```
params.setZoom(zoomValue);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Will things like white balance or auto focus stay untouched? And if so, can I be sure that this is the case for all android devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, `Camera.setParameters()` don't support defaults. That's why we always use the following sequence:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setZoom(zoomValue);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Often, people try to avoid multiple calls to `getParameters()` by using a member:

```
private Camera.Parameters mParams;

...

mCamera = Camera.open();
mParams = mCamera.getParameters();

...

params.setZoom(zoomValue);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

But there is one catch: as result of `setParameters()`, seemingly unrelated parameters may change; next time, if you use the same **mParams**, this may effect the result *(the examples are entirely specific to combination of hardware and system)*. Therefore I strongly recommend not to use cached camera parameters.

Comment: ok, so to make it clear: In your first example, if I set my zoom like that, will it effect other parameters that I have set before?

Comment: I won't be surprised if some regimes are not available for some zoom factors.